# Access nav bar button in code

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have a button on the right side of my nav bar, it is a `Done` button. I created it on my storyboard. I am trying to disable it in code. How can I access this button?

Comment: You really need to add an [Mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help explain your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways of do it:

1. As you have created the button using Interface Builder, then you can declare an `@IBOutlet` for it using the drag-and/drop utility of Xcode and disable/hide the button in the navigation bar in the following way:

   ```
   // hide the button
   self.rightButton.hidden = true

   // disable the button
   self.rightButton.enabled = false

   // change its title
   self.rightButton.setTitle("NEW TITLE", forState: .Normal)
   ```

   Where the `@IBOutlet` is like this:

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var rightButton: UIButton!
   ```
2. In case you don't want to declare any `@IBOutlet` you can set the `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` to `nil` in any place you want int this way:

   ```
   // remove the button
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil

   // disable the button
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.enabled = false
   ```

   And the above code disable any previous button you have set.

I hope this help you.

Comment: If I have an `@IBAction` connected to this button, can I also connect an `@IBOutlet` to it?

Comment: I got it. Thanks! One more question - I can disable and enable the button now. But why can't I print its title or change the title? Should I just create the button in code?

Answer (score 0):

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?
```

Comment: I tried `print(navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!.title)` and the result was nil.

Answer (score 0):

try to create outlet in your view controller: 
@IBOutlet weak var doneButton : UIBarButtonItem!
link the barbuttonItem  to your doneButton variable in the storyboard.

assigned the value false when to disable it.
At view did load:

doneButton.enabled = false

Answer (score 0):

```
if let iuRightNavigationButton = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
{
iuRightNavigationButton.enable = false
}
```

It basically checks for the rightBarbutton item,if there is one then it disables.You need not declare any iboutlet to do this